# the launch timed out and was terminated

Tags: cuda

I am using Tesla 2075 (cc 2.0) with CUDA 4.2. I am running my program on a non-display **GPU(Tesla)** and I am getting the error:

```
"the launch timed out and was terminated "
```

Is this error expected on a non-display GPU ?

And, how could I disable the watchdog timer ?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are running on Windows.  If so, put the Tesla 2075 in [TCC mode](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/ParallelNsight/2.1/Documentation/UserGuide/HTML/Content/Tesla_Compute_Cluster.htm).  This will allow compute access and Windows won't manage it like a display device, which will get rid of the watchdog timer.  If you're having trouble locating nvidia-smi, just do a windows search for nvidia-smi.exe.  (It should have been installed with the display driver.)  Then, if the C2075 is the only CUDA GPU in the system, the command will be like this:  `nvidia-smi -g 0 -dm 1`   You can also do `nvidia-smi --help` to get command line help  for the tool.  This will probably require a reboot of the system after you change this, to get the card into TCC mode.

If on the other hand you are running linux and X-windows on this machine, the solution is a little different.  One approach is simply to disable X, e.g. by setting runlevel to 3 and rebooting, but there are other ways to do this.  However you'll lose your X GUI on the other GPU (I assume you have another GPU since you said this is a non-display GPU).  To preserve X and the GUI on the other GPU, it's necessary to modify your xorg.conf file to force X onto your display GPU and get it off of your compute (Tesla) GPU.  The methods to do this will vary, but if you have 2 NVIDIA GPUs, (one for display) then the X display should be forced onto a single GPU using the BusID parameter in the relevant “Display” section of the xorg.conf file. In addition, any other “Display” sections should be deleted. For example:

```
 BusID “PCI:34:0:0”
```

The PCI IDs of the GPUs may be determined from the `lspci` command or from the `nvidia-smi –a` command.

You may also wish to refer to the [X configuration options appendix](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/310.19/README/xconfigoptions.html) of the NVIDIA driver [README file](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/310.19/README/index.html).

Comment: Thank you, that solution helped. I am using Ubuntu. Here is a [nvidia link](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3029/~/using-cuda-and-x) in which option 4 can be used to disable the watchdog timer all-together for X. It should be used if there are no concerns about display performance.

Comment: Option 4 in that link is intended for cases where you have only one GPU (both for display and compute tasks).  You made it sound like you have 2 GPUs.  If you have a 2075 GPU that is not for display tasks, it's better just to remove that GPU from X as I described in my answer.

Comment: I am using a cluster and each node has 2 GPUs - Tesla C2075 and GTX580, but due to some thermal restrictions in the chassis design the tesla cards are acting as primary display cards at the moment. So the only workaround I have presently is to disable the watchdog timer.